# Rogue Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, yii, foreign-keys

I'm using Yii and I'm getting this error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'fk_sub_sector_id'`

I've searched the whole DB

using

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 500
```

for the key and it doesn't seem to exist and I've looked in my models within Yii. Can't see any reference to it. Where else could it be hiding?

Comment: "Duplicate entry" suggest a UNIQUE KEY violation, not a FOREIGN KEY violation.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yeah, I discovered this, it was my own fault, I'd actually labelled the INDEX with a FK to show it was an index on a field being used as a FK and that was what confused me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

It was actually an index I had that was the problem, not an actual constraint.